# According to one thought "If you can't explain anything simply that means you don't understand it"

Tags: gods, philosophy

According to one thought "If you can't explain anything simply that means you don't understand it"

Does that mean we human beings don't certainly know about god also?

What's Hinduism's views on above saying ?

Comment: Knowing the god is different than knowing the things.

Comment: "I am not talking about science, from my understanding human beings......." @Rahulkr how many times do I need to tell - SCIENCE IS OFF TOPIC. You again used the word 'science'.

Comment: Accept the answers by clicking on check mark, if you are satisfied.

Answer (score 15):

**human beings don't know about god am I right?**

See what [**Kena-Upanishad**](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://estudantedavedanta.net/Kena%2520Upanishad%2520-%2520Swami%2520Sarvanand%2520%5BSanskrit-English%5D.pdf&ved=0ahUKEwi0-PjY3-fTAhXHQ48KHcrMBgIQFggoMAI&usg=AFQjCNGclbyHOlNwvZDCBPbUNb2dH1DsEw&sig2=VkisdnTnc4cR6oy66-xqWQ) says about your question.

> यस्यमतं तस्य मतं मतं यस्य न वेद स:।
>   अविज्ञातं विजानतां
>   विज्ञातमविजानताम ॥3॥
>
> YasyaMatam Tasya Matam Matam Yasya na Ved sa 
>   AvigyanTam
>   Vijanatam  VigyanTaMaVijanaTam
>
> He who thinks he does not know It, knows It.  He who thinks he knows
>   It, does not know It. The true knowers think they can never know It
>   (because of Its infinitude), while the  ignorant think they know It.
>
> **Kena-Upanishad Khand -2 ,Shloka 3**
>
> ---
>
> This verse brings out how we struggle with difficulties of human expression and insufficiency of mental utterance. By this text the teacher confirms the idea that **Brahman is unthinkable,** because it is unconditioned.  Therefore he says: **He who considers It beyond thought, beyond sense perception, beyond mind and speech, he alone has a true understanding of Brahman.**

Comment: Very well answered.

Comment: Thanks a lot @SwiftPushkar this is what I was searching for

Comment: @Rahulkr - Thank you for your comment. Pls.do participate frequently on this site.Feel free to ask Questions & provide answers (with sources)  here.And if you think this is right answer  Pls. do accept it. :-)

Comment: Should we rule out all the guru who had said I have seen God or experience the infinite light.. Because he doesn't know, But all these gurus have large following.. so which one is real. To simplify I have thumb rule brahma sutra commentary. one who had written commentary on prasthana thrya scripture is the authentic

Answer (score 0):

Use of the verb "know" is contradictory with "belief". God was (and is) a part of believe system even in the time of ramayana. That's why the words "theist" or "atheist" (nastik) appeared in the texts. If there exists an word for atheists in texts it means God has always been part of a "belief system".

Like a knowledge a belief system is also **explainable** and **aggreable**. Often the term **understandable** is used to refer **aggreable** and **convincible**. So those who can explain god **believes** (understands) w.r.t. those who also believes (**simple**).

Those who **believes** (read understands) but fails to convince (read explain) others don't understand (read have enough convincing power) as the previous case.

And those who don't **believe** (read understand) don't bother to convince (read explain) others.